# To present JSON key value in Angular front end

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to present the below JSON in the front end (Angular 1).

```
{
"test.employee.name" : "Royal"
}
```

Want to present both the key and the value in the front end. The json data will be stored in a .json file.

Comment: You should show what you have tried and what doesn't work, instead of just asking for someone to hand you code.

Comment: @Claies - I am new to this. Thanks for your info!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
     vm.events = {
"test.employee.name" : "Royal"
};
  }

]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl as home">
  <div  ng-repeat="(key,value) in home.events  "> 
 "key is:" {{key }}  "value is:" {{value}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```